# swift3 dictionary limitation Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

(currently on Xcode 8.2 and swift3)

Once I update to swift3, I have this error

> "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11"

Since I have a large number of `keys` & `values` in a single dictionary.

When I dig out, I have find that the dictionary has limited keys and values, and when I add more than specific number of keys & values, the above error shows up.

- What is the best way to resolve this error?
- How to make the dictionary accommodates more keys and values?

  ```
  import Foundation

  open class TranslateDictionary {

      var translateDictionary: [String: String] = [

          "alphabetic": "one",
          "categories": "two",
          "levels": "three",
          "mlevel1": "four",
          "mlevel2": "five",
          "mlevel3": "six",
          "mlevel4": "seven",
          "mlevel5": "eight",
          "mlevel6": "nine",

                 //It contain a lot of keys and values not just those above!
  ]



      func toArabic(_ label: String) -> String {
          var arabic = translateDictionary[label]

          if (arabic == nil) {
              arabic = "NoTranslation"
          }

          return arabic!
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Is this a Dictionary literal?

Comment: Its a swift3 Dictionary structure consist of key and value

Comment: How many key/value pairs are you trying to insert?

Comment: Yeah I get that, but it is the dictionary generated programmatically, or by a dictionary literal?

Comment: @PauloMattos More than 1000's I believe :)

Comment: @Alexander All the keys and values were literally defined

Comment: @NasserAlSnayen So, did my answer below fixed your problem?

Comment: @Paulo Mattos I haven't tried it yet, it won't show me until I modified all the code and hitting the size limit, then I can see if it works or not ;( is there any other way to avoid size limitation?

Comment: I highly recommend `NSLocalizedString`.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting your keys like this:

```
var translateDictionary: [String: String] = {
    var translateDictionary = [String: String]()
    translateDictionary["key1"] = "value1"
    translateDictionary["key2"] = "value2"
    ...
    return translateDictionary
}()
```

You might be hitting a *size limit* for dictionary literals.

By the way, your `toArabic` function will look a lot more *Swifty* like this ;-)

```
func toArabic(_ label: String) -> String {
    guard let arabic = translateDictionary[label] else {
        return "NoTranslation"
    }
    return arabic
}
```

Comment: I tried your above code but it gives me an expected declaration in the 2nd line  ---> translateDictionary["key1"] = "value1"

Comment: @NasserAlSnayen If my answer cleared your issue, pls be sure to mark it as the accepted answer when you get a chance... thanks man!